# initializing floating point numbers with std::numeric_limits::max();

Tags: c++, floating-point

Can someone explain why the output of the following piece of code is as below?

```
float x = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
float y = x - 1.0f;

if(x==y)
    std::cout << "x is equal y!\n";
else 
    std::cout << "x is not equal y!\n";

std::cout << std::fixed << "x: " << x << "\n";
std::cout << std::fixed << "y: " << y << "\n";
```

On my machine, where the size of a `float` is 4 bytes, the output looks like this:

```
x is equal y!
x: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
y: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
```

Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: See [the Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). You have a type with presumably around 4 billion possible values. There's no way it can store every integer up to 340282346638528859811704183484516925440, never mind that there are an infinite number of values between each integer.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<float>::max() - 1` isn't representable as a float so you get `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` as the answer instead as it's the closest representable value to the answer

Comment: What you could use instead: [std::nexttoward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter): [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f686f2bdf92a8b2f).